# How to check JSON conditions in Failed status in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, validation, if-statement

From JSON i am getting success and failed status, i am able to check success status but here unable to check failed status conditions in Login. login page contains PhoneNumber and Password textfields.

**here if i enter non registered phone number i need to show below msg in alert:**

> ["status": Failed, "msg": Phone number does not exist]

**if i enter wrong password for phonenumber then i need to show below msg in alert:**

> ["status": Failed, "msg": You have entered wrong password]

**if i enter wrong phone number and password then i need to show below msg in alert:**

> ["status": Failed, "msg": Invalid Credentials]

but i am unable to check all conditions, all the time i am getting only `Invalid Credentials` if i enter wrong password or non registered phone number also.

In register page here i am getting `uid` for successful registration with phonenumber and password:

```
do {
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
print("the json of otppppppppp \(json)")
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if (self.otpTextField.text == String(self.otpField ?? 12)){
        print("registration successfullllll...")
        let mobileNum = json["mobile_number"] as! [String : Any]
        self.regUid = mobileNum["id"] as? String
        let name = mobileNum["name"] as? String
        let phNum = mobileNum["username"] as? String
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            KeychainWrapper.standard.set(self.regUid!, forKey: "regUid")
            KeychainWrapper.standard.set(phNum!, forKey: "user_phnum")
            KeychainWrapper.standard.set(self.passwordTextField.text!, forKey: "user_password")
        }
       
        let loginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
        self.present(loginVC, animated: true)
    }
}
}
```

In login page unable to check if the phonenumber is registred or not and is that wrong password or not for registered mobile.

all the time i am showing `Invalid Credentials` for failed status:

```
do {
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
print("the json of loginnnnnn \(json)")
var loginStatus = json["status"] as? String
    
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if loginStatus == "Failed"
    {
        AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "Invalid Credentials", in: self)
    }
    else{
        self.Uid = json["id"] as? String
        
        let emailL = json["user_email"] as? String
        print("login uid \(String(describing: self.Uid))")
        
        KeychainWrapper.standard.set(emailL ?? "", forKey: "user_email")
        let saveUserId: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(self.Uid!, forKey: "Uid")
        
        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let navigationController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeNavigation")
        let appDelagate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
        appDelagate?.window??.rootViewController = navigationController
    }
}
}
```

Please help me to check above conditions in login page.

Comment: If I understood you, "wrong password" response will come back from login request to server. In this case loginStatus should have this value. And please, work on your English. It's very hard do understand the question.

Comment: @RealNmae, from server i am getting one success  status and in failed status i am getting different message for different condition, like if notregistred phhone number means `phone number doesn't exist`, and registred phone num with wrong password means `you have entered wron password`, and if i enter phnum and password wrong means `invalid credentials`..

Comment: @RealNmae, I have edited my question please help

Comment: What you can do is just display the "msg" value. And check for status to show different colors (Or any other logic). if(status == "Success"){dosomething}else{dosomething}

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking. No code checks  "msg" so how do you expect to know what it is?

Comment: @Bikram, i have edited my post, please help me in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to display different messages based on the status you get from the JSON.

You can simply do this.

AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: **json["msg"]**, in: self)

To be safe should unwrap the value of json["msg"] using guard statement and show it in the Alert.

Comment: you are correct, i am not giving json "msg" , i am giving my own message in alert thats why problem raised, thank you issue solved, i know its silly mistake, but i am really new to ios

Comment: No worries. You will catch up easily.